# Comapring DATE_ADD with NOW not working on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, where-clause

I've try to compare an `DateTime` in `MySQL`.

The table is to check locked users. For sample, an User will be locked for `1 Day` at the DateTime `2020-04-09 14:51:32`:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    DATE_ADD(`time_created`, INTERVAL `locked_time` DAY) AS `until`
FROM
    `' . DATABASE_PREFIX . 'users_locked`
WHERE
    `user_id`=:user_id
LIMIT 1
```

`until` is the datetime `time_created` with added days from `locked_time`.

Here is the Result of entries:

```
object(stdClass)[53]
  public 'id' => string '1'
  public 'user_id' => string '2'
  public 'locked_by' => string '1'
  public 'time_created' => string '2020-04-09 14:51:32'
  public 'locked_time' => string '1'
  public 'reason' => string 'This is a test'
  public 'until' => string '2020-04-10 14:51:32'
```

The calculation (`time_created` with added `locked_time` with the result `2020-04-10 14:51:32`) is correctly. But when i try to compare this value with an current timestamp (like `NOW()`), no results are available - Whether I use `>=` or `<=`:

```sql
[...]
WHERE
    `user_id`=:user_id
AND
    `until`<=NOW()
LIMIT 1
```

```sql
[...]
WHERE
    `user_id`=:user_id
AND
    `until`>=NOW()
LIMIT 1
```

How can I check if the date is 'until' within 'NOW()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions defined in the `SELECT` clause are not available in the `WHERE` clause (the latter is evaluated *before* the former). You would need to repeat the expression:

```
SELECT
    *,
    DATE_ADD(`time_created`, INTERVAL `locked_time` DAY) AS `until`
FROM
    `' . DATABASE_PREFIX . 'users_locked`
WHERE
    `user_id`=:user_id
     AND DATE_ADD(`time_created`, INTERVAL `locked_time` DAY) >= NOW()
LIMIT 1
```